# 7 Day Average Cases Form

Tags: c#

I am a newbie and I am honestly struggling a lot with this. I am trying to calculate all the entries from the texbox to the listbox and then divide by 7 and display the average in an output label. I am having trouble displaying the case average. Here is the code:

```
public partial class formAverageWeeklyCases : Form
{ 
    int SEVEN = 7;

    public formAverageWeeklyCases()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void buttonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBoxCaseEntry.Text.Trim().Length >= 1)
        {
            listBoxDailyCases.Items.Add(textBoxCaseEntry.Text.Trim());
            textBoxCaseEntry.Text = string.Empty;
            textBoxCaseEntry.Focus();
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The number entered does not appear to be valid");
            textBoxCaseEntry.Text = string.Empty;
            textBoxCaseEntry.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxCaseEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        listBoxDailyCases.Items.Clear();
        labelOutputDailyAverage.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void textBoxAverageWeeklyCases_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBoxDailyCases.SelectedItems.Count <= SEVEN)
        {
            double average = listBoxDailyCases.SelectedItems.Count / SEVEN;

            labelOutputDailyAverage.Text.Show(+average);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a only 7 case count numbers");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to collect 7 numbers from the user and then calculate the average? If yes, I suggest you declare a list of ints (or doubles if you need doubles), then call `TryParse` to validate the user input and then calculate the average when needed:

```cs
public partial class formAverageWeeklyCases : Form
{
    const int SEVEN = 7;
    private List<int> numbers = new List<int>(SEVEN); // NEW

    public formAverageWeeklyCases()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void buttonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(textBoxCaseEntry.Text.Trim(), out int parsed)) // NEW
        {
            numbers.Add(parsed); // NEW
            textBoxCaseEntry.Text = string.Empty;
            textBoxCaseEntry.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The number entered does not appear to be valid");
            textBoxCaseEntry.Text = string.Empty;
            textBoxCaseEntry.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxCaseEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        listBoxDailyCases.Items.Clear();
        labelOutputDailyAverage.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void textBoxAverageWeeklyCases_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBoxDailyCases.SelectedItems.Count <= SEVEN)
        {
            double average = numbers.Sum() / SEVEN; // NEW

            labelOutputDailyAverage.Text = average.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a only 7 case count numbers");
        }
    }
}
```